# How to send messages across two Erlang Nodes

Tags: erlang

The code in my two Erlang Modules are as follows:

**recevier:**

```
start() ->
    PID = spawn(?MODULE, message_box, []),
    PID.

message_box() ->
    sender:start_link(),
    receive
        {From, take_this_message} ->
            From ! "ok thanks !";
        {From, fish} ->
            From ! "So long and thanks for all the fish";
        _  ->
            io:format("Received Nothing~n")
        end.
```

**sender:**

```
-module(sender).

-compile(export_all).

start_link() ->
    PID = spawn_link(?MODULE, init, [self()]),
    PID.

init(PID) ->
    PID ! {self(), "Wassup!"}.
```

I want receiver to display Received Nothing after calling start_link().
Also how do I check the messages a module/process has received in runtime using the shell or otherwise?

```
**ERROR MESSAGE:**  

=ERROR REPORT==== 21-Jul-2014::12:42:44 ===
Error in process <0.40.0> with exit value: {undef,[{sender,start_link,[],[]},{receiver,message_box,0,[{file,"receiver.erl"},{line,14}]}]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to exchange messages across the 2 nodes, you must first start 2 nodes (erl -sname foo, erl -sname bar) associate them in a cluster. This can be done using the net_adm:ping/1 function: `net_adm:ping(foo@domain) on the bar node.` should return you pong. (If you get pang, then chek the spelling, check that the 2 nodes have the same cookie), or net_kernel:connect(foo@domain) should return ok.

Then you can launch the receiver process on one node, and get its Pid from the second node for example `rpc:call(foo@domain,erlang,processes,[]).` will return the list of all processes pid runing on the node foo.

You can then run the send function on the second node, and you will get the returned message in the shell message queue.

This because the send function use self() to give the pid where to return an answer, and it is run in the shell process (the is no new process spawned).

If you spawn your function without change, the return message will be lost, because the process will die immediately after the first message is sent. you need to modify it lije this for example:

```
-module(sender).

-compile(export_all).

init(PID,Mess) ->
    spawn(?MODULE,send_receive,[PID,Mess]).

send_receive(PID,Mess) ->
    PID ! {self(), Mess},
    R = receive
        M -> {ok,M}
    after 5000 -> {error,"no answer!"}
    end,
    io:format("~p~n",[R]).

-module (receiver).

-compile(export_all).

start() ->
    PID = spawn(?MODULE, message_box, []),
    PID.

message_box() ->
    receive
        {From, take_this_message} ->
            From ! "ok thanks !";
        {From, fish} ->
            From ! "So long and thanks for all the fish";
        _  ->
            io:format("Received Nothing~n")
        end.
```

in the shells:

```
(foo@W7FRR00423L)3> receiver:start().
<0.50.0>
Received Nothing    
(foo@W7FRR00423L)4> receiver:start().
<0.53.0>
(foo@W7FRR00423L)5> receiver:start().
<0.55.0>
Received Nothing    
(foo@W7FRR00423L)6> 



(bar@W7FRR00423L)1> net_kernel:connect(foo@W7FRR00423L).
true
(bar@W7FRR00423L)2> nodes().
[foo@W7FRR00423L]
(bar@W7FRR00423L)3> rpc:call(foo@W7FRR00423L,erlang,processes,[]).
[<6075.0.0>,<6075.3.0>,<6075.6.0>,<6075.7.0>,<6075.9.0>,
 <6075.10.0>,<6075.11.0>,<6075.12.0>,<6075.13.0>,<6075.14.0>,
 <6075.15.0>,<6075.16.0>,<6075.17.0>,<6075.18.0>,<6075.19.0>,
 <6075.20.0>,<6075.21.0>,<6075.22.0>,<6075.23.0>,<6075.24.0>,
 <6075.25.0>,<6075.26.0>,<6075.27.0>,<6075.28.0>,<6075.29.0>,
 <6075.30.0>,<6075.31.0>,<6075.32.0>,<6075.33.0>|...]
(bar@W7FRR00423L)4> sender:init(pid(6075,50,0),take_this_message).
<0.55.0>
{error,"no answer!"}
(bar@W7FRR00423L)5> sender:init(pid(6075,53,0),take_this_message).
<0.57.0>
{ok,"ok thanks !"}  
(bar@W7FRR00423L)6> sender:init(pid(6075,55,0),"Wassup!").        
<0.59.0>
{error,"no answer!"}
(bar@W7FRR00423L)7>
```

*[edit]*

As said in comment, generally the communication goes through registered processes (this is equally true on a single node) when the 2 processes are created independently, for example you can modify the receiver like this:

```
start() ->
    PID = spawn(?MODULE, message_box, []),
    register(?MODULE,PID),
    PID.
```

and then send the message using the syntax {name,node} to send the message: `sender:init({receiver,bar@W7FRR00423L},take_this_message).`

Or you can create the 2 processes from one single node like this:

```
(foo@W7FRR00423L)4> Pid = rpc:call(bar@W7FRR00423L,receiver,start,[]).           
<5974.54.0> 
(foo@W7FRR00423L)5> sender:init(Pid,fish).
<0.50.0>
{ok,"So long and thanks for all the fish"}
(foo@W7FRR00423L)6>
```

Comment: Is there any other method to identify the PID of receiver other than trial and error?

Comment: Generally you use registered processes, so you can access them by name, and the name stays the same if you have to restart the process. I'll post an updated version of the code using registered processes.

Comment: But your implementation seems more useful

Comment: Say, I want to create a link to sender inside the receiver program.
What parameters should I pass to `spawn_link/4` ?

Comment: In Erlang a link is a bidirectional connection, managed by the system, that guarantee that all the processes linked together (like in a mesh) will die together. If you use spawn_link/4 you will link the calling process with the new spawned one (for example the shell with the receiver); you don't need any parameter to do that. I guess what you want is to link the sender to the receiver, in this case simply modify the send_receive function by adding at the beginning : `link(PID),` then the receiver will die as soon as the sender finishes, after the first message!